How can I restore my customized desktop appearance after Ubuntu crash?
I opened too many windows in Chrome and Chrome crashed. Then the computer behaved a bit oddly (not responding) and I had to do a REISUB shutdown. It rebooted fine, and all the files and software are there. BUT the carefully crafted appearance of the desktop is gone! It seems to have applied the default settings, and all my little plasmashell tweaks like my menu bars and their placements etc. are gone. Also, the background is different (it's a cool pixellated jellyfish). And a few of my custom commands don't work (e.g. I set up Ctrl-Alt-Esc to give me a red skull and crossbones that kills any window you click it on, but that has disappeared.) Oddly, it remembers the colouring and font that I chose for Dolphin and system settings windows, but not most of the other stuff. Currently running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
I am at novice level, but is there a fast way I can point it to my customized settings instead of doing it all again? I believe I may have it backed up in case it has somehow been corrupted, though I've been having trouble with backintime the last while and can't be certain till I look.
